# How to select all values from some ID based on condition in other column?

Tags: r, grouping, subset

I got a data frame like in an example and I would select all values all IDs and all of the values from that ID when the condition is met. Condition, in this case, would be that path must contain `"one"`.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                 path=c("one", "two", "three", "four", "oned", "five", "six", 
                        "seven", "eight"))
```

Expected result:

```
result <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                     path=c("one", "two", "three", "four", "oned", "five"))
```

What is the most elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

We can use dplyr for that. just `group_by` ID, then filter groups with `any(str_detect('one'))`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
       filter(any(str_detect(path, 'one')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grepl` in `ave`.

```
df[with(df, as.logical(ave(path, id, FUN=\(x) any(grepl('one', x))))), ]
#   id  path
# 1  1   one
# 2  1   two
# 3  1 three
# 4  2  four
# 5  2  oned
# 6  2  five
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), path = c("one", 
"two", "three", "four", "oned", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A one row code can be this:

```
result <- df[df$id %in% df[grepl('one',df$path),"id"],]
```

It's just combine native [ ] operator and [grepl function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep).

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant way but it's my approach :

```
my_df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                path = c("one","two","three", "four", "oned", "five","six", "seven", "eight"))

my_value <- my_df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(Test = grepl(pattern = "one", x = path)) %>% filter(Test == TRUE)
my_var <- which(my_df$id %in% my_value$id)
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_df <- my_df[my_var,]
}
```